# NetBIOS visibility in Windows IoT Core

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

I am trying different approaches to creating a simple NAS using a Raspberry Pi and decided to give Windows IoT Core a try; considering that other computers in my network are primarily Windows and drives are NTFS, that seemed like a viable idea.

I managed to install and run Windows IoT Core on my RPi and I managed to set up an SMB share via remote Powershell session, everything went quite smoothly.

However, I can't make this share be visible over the network (i.e., in Network Neighborhood). After some research, it seems that this visibility is achieved by NetBIOS name service (similar to what [nmbd](https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/4/RH-DOCS/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-samba-daemons.html) does). So somehow Windows IoT Core doesn't announce itself to the network through NetBIOS protocol. At the same time, I am able to access the Pi through its device name (`\\raspberrypi\`), which means that it supports NetBIOS...

Is there any way to make the SMB shares on Windows IoT Core visible in the Network Neighborhood?